# How to read a curl post with PHP

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2

I'm using `curl` to post JSON to PHP and i'm struggling to read the data in PHP.

#### This is how i'm using `curl` ,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"admin@example.com","password":"xyz"}' http://example.com/api/login
```

#### This is what iv'e tried in PHP

1) Using ZF2 functions:

```
$email = (string) $this->params()->fromPost('email', null);
```

2) and

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

But neither of the above work.

#### What is the correct way to read a post from CURL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you pass a JSON object string as the http body. to do what you described, you need to decode the incoming JSON string to do so.

You can use `json_decode` and `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the email into a variable:

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$email = $body['email'];
echo $email
```

---

### But why your example failed?

You've treated the `email` as if it came as a form post param. but since you passed it in `curl` as a JSON string in the body, the `$_POST['email']` came out to be without the value you expected.

If your client behavior was similar to the following, your example should work:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="myfile.php" method="post">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, but why would the other methods not work?

Comment: @HappyCoder because you tried to use them as if they came from `form` post params. which they are not (they came from JSON body post) :)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem with Apigility posted json. This is how I solved it. This may work for you, depending on what request type you have.

```
$data = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getContent(), true);
$email = $data['email'];
echo $email
```

In case it might help someone else integrating Apigility and ZfcUser, this is a little hack I came up with to convert the Json payload to Post params

```
    /** @var \ZF\ContentNegotiation\Request $request */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $contentArray = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    // Turn content into a Post, because the ZfcUser triggered events expect form data in the Post
    $newPost = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters($contentArray);
    $request->setPost($newPost);
```